# Packaging a js library for AMD, CommonJS and more

Tags: javascript, module, requirejs, amd, commonjs

When packaging a javascript library that needs to be used with AMD, CommonJS or as a global, it is common to use a defition such as the following:

```
(function(name, definition) {
    if (typeof module != 'undefined') module.exports = definition();
    else if (typeof define == 'function' && typeof define.amd == 'object') define(definition);
    else this[name] = definition();
}('mod', function() {
    //Here goes the code you would normally have inside define() or add to module.exports
    return MyModule
    };
}));
```

This works well assuming your library consists of only a single file, with no external dependencies. I am not sure what to do when publishing a library that consists of various interdependent modules, possibly with external dependencies.

Even if I only want to support AMD (AMD + Bower is my main use case, i.e. the way I will use the library myself), I am not sure which is the way to go. Assume my library publishes modules `foo` and `bar`, with `bar` depending on `foo`, both having `external` as a dependency. I could try to do something like

```
// mylib/foo.js
define(['external'], function(external) {
  // whatever
});
// mylib/bar.js
define(['./foo', 'external'], function(foo, external) {
  // whatever
});
```

Still, I am not guaranteed that a client of mine would resolve 'external' correctly. For this to work, the client would need to explicitly add the path for `external` in its RequireJS definition. This is still doable, if there is just one dependency, but I would prefer to shield the client from having to know that the library uses external. This should be declared in my `bower.json` and `package.json` files, but the client should not mess with transitive dependencies manually. As soon as a library has multiple dependencies, each one having other dependencies, things can get hairy.

> What is the correct way to handle dependencies in a library, especially considering the possibility of supporting multiple module standards?

Answer (score 1):

I would have used the r.js to merge modules into one file (of course, only internal dependencies).

I'm not sure if I understood your problem correctly but several modules merged into one file would solve your problem.

You focused on question, RequireJS docs already posted an example: http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html

*edit*: look at the tail of jquery.js - they dealt with such an approach: https://gist.github.com/er1z/7721573

Comment: Unfortunately, the output of `r.js` still has some drawback. First, it depends itself on RequireJS, which makes it not suitable for the CommonJS and global use cases. Moreover, I would rather not include external dependencies inside my library, but leave them as dependencies. I will try to read the docs you posted, though, maybe that will work.

Comment: By the way, my problem, if it is not clear from the question, is publishing a library, with the following constraints. 1. The library consists of several modules; 2. The library has external dependencies; 3. Clients should be able to use the library either in AMD, CommonJS or as a global.

Comment: Thank you. :-) The approach you suggest is equivalent to the first snipper in my question. The problem is, this only works for a single monolithic library with no dependencies. The issue I am trying to solve is how to make this work in presence of external and internal dependencies.

Comment: So why don't you write a resolver using simillar approach? #1 - test the env and check which (AMD/Node) dependency manager is present, #2 - load. This is the first idea I came across: https://gist.github.com/er1z/7721672

Comment: Well, that may work! I will try to use this approach and let you know if it works. I may have to work around some issues because doing this literally would break the r.js minification script, but is seems promising

Comment: Well, you can always overload "define" function to satisfy r.js working by that approach. [: